# launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой, что дублируется класс. Уже выяснил, что конфликтует библиотека -myTrackerSDK с OneSignal и в коде ошибки еще как будто есть 2 библиотеки с разными версиями, но это не так, проверял на чистом проекте. Перепробовал почти все возможные варианты которые нашел в интернете по этому вопросу, но не один из них не сработал. Если кто-то знает возможное решение по данной проблеме, прошу поделиться даже самыми неочевидными.
Вот код ошибки

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.31f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: D:\Unity\Fortune Wheel\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbs found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzcc found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzcd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zze found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.zze found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:signingConfigWriterRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
38 actionable tasks: 38 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <cdf6c87974604af79a3a65a0b3c0eebd>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <a259d3c004024353a2c217da97495055>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было поменять версию с 12.1.0 на 15.0.1

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 15.0.1[' // Packages/com.onesignal.unity.android/Editor/OneSignalDependencies
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1, 15.0.1[' // Packages/com.onesignal.unity.android/Editor/OneSignalDependencies
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 15.0.1[' // Packages/com.onesignal.unity.android/Editor/OneSignalDependencies
```